# Open all hyperlinks in default browser

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

i spent the past 3 hrs trying to find a solution but haven't got much. some were close but dint work for me. (Process.Start or shell thing is not working for me as i want all hyperlinks in a particular website to open in default browser instead of IE. below is the code i am using.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Try
        If IsConnectionAvailable("http://google.com") = True Then
            MapBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost")
            '  Me.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ImgBackground)
        Else
            MapBrowser.Navigate("http://yahoo.com")
          Timer4.Start()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())
    End Try
```

Comment: `Process.Start()` will indeed open things in the default browser.  If IE is opening, then IE is your default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the `Navigating` event on the browser control, and then handle the ones you want to open in a new window.  `Process.Start()` will open the default browser.  If it opens IE for you, then IE is your default browser.

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) _
    Handles webBrowser1.Navigating

    If Not (e.Url = "some URL you don't want to pop up in new window") Then
        Process.Start(e.Url.ToString())
        e.Cancel = true
    End If
End Sub
```

Untested, but you get the idea.

Comment: i have multiple browsers in my form so to identify that i gave different name each browser.

Comment: hi Brad thanks for the help. but i tried this and its not helping. whati am trying to do is load a web page in vb app browser and if somebody clicks on a hyperlink, it should open in default (in this case is chrome) instead of ie. what the above code suggest is to load the initial url itself in the default browser which i don't want. Example: www.mysite.com should open in vb app. and all www.mysite.com links should open in default browser. I hope i explained my problem properly.

Comment: If you read my example again, you will see that I am proposing you do exactly what you are asking.  You of course will need to check the `e.Url` property to see if it is a URL that should be loaded in your app.  A simple `if` block will do.

Comment: Thanks brad.. I am just self learning .net. so you mean that in if block i can set e.Cancel = flase (if its www.mysite.com) e.Cancel = true (if its www.mysite.com/links this can be anything so cant specify a specific url for example, links in www.mysite.com can take a user to yahoo or google or facebook or stackoverflow.. it can be anything)? I have to go now but will try it tomorrow and will let you know. it will be very helpful if you can provide me any further help with some sample code. another wild guess.. will this help if i try webBrowser1.NewWindow instead webBrowser1.Navigating?

Comment: If your links are set to open in a new window, then you may want to try handling that event instead.  I have edited my answer with an example for conditional logic to not open in a new window.

Comment: Yes all my links should open in a new window (default browser) as most my clients use firefox or chrome. can you please proved any sample to handle that?

Comment: Please, read what I have posted.  `Process.Start()` will launch the default browser.

Comment: Ok. Here is what happening.. when i use process.start, webBrowser1.Navigate("http://yahoo.com") its opening up in chrome which was meant to (this i don't want) and the inbuilt browser (vb app) shows a blank white screen). all i want is to load www.yahoo.com in vb app  and all links(ex:www.yahoomail.com_blank) in www.yahoo.com open up in chrome.

Comment: all so i got an error why using the if condition Error 2 Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean': Value of type 'System.Uri' cannot be converted to 'String'.
    'Public Shared Operator =(uri1 As System.Uri, uri2 As System.Uri) As Boolean': Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Uri'.

Comment: Yes, of course.  You need to filter out what URLs you want to open in your app.  See that `if` block in the code?  Do your filtering there.  `If Not (e.URL = "http://www.yahoo.com") Then`, and then you use `Process.Start`.  Otherwise, you don't.

Comment: Use `.ToString()` on your URLs.  Sorry, I don't have Visual Studio on me.  You will need to debug things like this.  So you will use `e.Url.ToString()` when comparing to string literal URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad. will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks brad for all your help. i made a small change and it worked like charm.

Comment: Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating( _
       ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
       Handles MapBrowser.NewWindow

        If Not MapBrowser.Url.ToString = "http://localhost/mapbrow" Then
            Process.Start(MapBrowser.Url.ToString())
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles webBrowser1.Navigating
'if the url isnt a part of your site
If Not e.Url.ToString().Contains("http://yoursite.com") Then
    Process.Start(e.Url.ToString())
    e.Cancel = true
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Brad's example, you can make something like this, which will load the first page in the web browser control and all subsequent links in the default browser:

```
Private Sub Form1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    OpenAllInBrowser = False   ' This is to reset the variable to False, because
End Sub                        ' sometimes closing the form doesn't reset the variables.

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    OpenAllInBrowser = True
End Sub

Private OpenAllInBrowser As Boolean = False

Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    If OpenAllInBrowser Then
        Process.Start(e.Url.ToString())
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.